# How to resolve the exception System.IO.IOException: 'the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, exception, filepath

```
 public ActionResult Download(DateTime? downloaddate)
    {
        {
            string path1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "logs/";
            string filename = "industrialcomm-payload-" + downloaddate + ".txt";
            byte[] filebytes1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path1 + filename);
            string contentType1 = "text/plain";

            return File(filebytes1, contentType1);
        }
```

I get an exception on filebytes1 and I'm wondering how to resolve the issue. I have parameter called downloaddate which is a calendar date picker in HTML. Every time I pick a date and click the button, I get an  exception System.IO.IOException: 'the filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you ever checked what "path1 + filename" value is at runtime?

Comment: `DateTime` will have `/` characters which are not safe for file names. I expect you will need to format the date to match what the file name actually has.

Comment: @burcinsahin Yes, I did and the path matches where the location of the file is.

Answer (score 0):

I created a variable called Date and set is as a New DateTime. Then, referenced the variable Date to downloaddate parameter.

Here's the code:

```
DateTime Date = new DateTime();
Date = (DateTime)downloaddate;

string path1 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "logs/";
string filename = "industrialcomm-payload-" + Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".log";
byte[] filebytes1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(path1 + filename);
string contentType1 = "text/plain";

return File(filebytes1, contentType1, filename);
```

This will set the calender downloaddate to DateTime().